# Improve closed for recommendation text

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, recommendation-questions, software-recs-se

When a question is closed as off-topic because it's a question seeking an off-site resource the text looks like:

> put on hold as off-topic by Marc B, Quentin, Paulie_D, Alohci, Rodger
>   3 mins ago
>
> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it." – Marc B, Quentin, Paulie_D, Alohci, Rodger If this question can
>   be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your
>   question.

It seems like a good place to link to [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) in this text.

If would be even better if we could add that link during the creation of any question that has "recommendation" in the title or something similar - maybe throw it into the similar questions box or something?

Comment: Have you asked softwarerecs whether they would find that acceptable (via their meta). I'm pretty sure you'll get a resounding **no**. They don't want our garbage.

Comment: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: Don't tell people who can't post on topic where to go.

Comment: So we don't answer questions about software recommendations and despite having a software recommendations part of stack exchange we don't point them there???  o.O

Comment: I'll check there. if there isn't a resounding 'no' then the link Bart posted would probably be the place to link to.

Answer (score 13):

We've gone over this before. Software Recommendations has a very specific set of guidelines on how to ask, and we're a much smaller site than Stack Overflow.

SR really doesn't need SO to funnel all of the people who *didn't read the guidelines in the first place* over. A vast majority won't read the guidelines on SR, and we're not equipped to handle a huge influx of close-worthy questions.

Comment: We should just get rid of the site recommendation part of our close reasons. Super User and Server Fault don't need our crap either.